# Error in caph framework

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I am using caph framework. In my source line 
var Scene = caph.require('ui.base.Scene') 
it is showing an error

i.e.

'caph' was used before it was defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the caph related JS and CSS files before using them in your code. i.e before execution of caph.require api, your caph related files must be loaded. You need to include caph js and css files before the execution of any caph related api.